# Update multiple keys with values of a dictionary after a loop has run and updated values that are used to update the dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to update a dictionary that is initialized at the start of the method/function and later the corresponding values of the keys should be updated with the counter variables in the function. But, for some reasons my dictionary is not getting updated. Please advise.

Code:

```
def quizresult(quiz_df):
maxmarks=10.0
noofpresent,lessthanfifty,betweenfiftyandsixty,betweensixtyandseventy,betweenseventyandeighty,greaterthaneighty=0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
quiz_result={'noofpresent':None,'lessthan50':None,'between50and60':None,'between60and70':None,'between70and80':None,'greaterthan80':None}
for i in range(len(quiz_df)):

    noofpresent=len(quiz_df.index)
    if(float(quiz_df.loc[i,'Grade/10.00'])/maxmarks)<0.5:
        lessthanfifty += 1
    if((float(quiz_df.loc[i,'Grade/10.00'])/maxmarks)>=0.5 and (float(quiz_df.loc[i,'Grade/10.00'])/maxmarks)<0.6):
        betweenfiftyandsixty += 1
    if((float(quiz_df.loc[i,'Grade/10.00'])/maxmarks)>=0.6 and (float(quiz_df.loc[i,'Grade/10.00'])/maxmarks)<0.7):
        betweensixtyandseventy += 1
    if((float(quiz_df.loc[i,'Grade/10.00'])/maxmarks)>=0.7 and (float(quiz_df.loc[i,'Grade/10.00'])/maxmarks)<0.8):
        betweenseventyandeighty += 1
    if(float(quiz_df.loc[i,'Grade/10.00'])/maxmarks)>=0.8:
        greaterthaneighty += 1
quiz_result.update({'noofpresent':noofpresent,'lessthan50':lessthanfifty,'between50and60':betweenfiftyandsixty,'between60and70':betweensixtyandseventy,'between70and80':betweenseventyandeighty,'greaterthan80':greaterthaneighty})

return quiz_result
```

P.S: Indentation is not an issue here. I get following message:

"SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  after removing the cwd from sys.path."

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: Ok, can you give us an example dataframe, and ensure that your code you have provided for us is giving you the same error - I cannot reproduce this error

Comment: Sampe Data

  enrollmentnumber  admn  studentname       BatchNo Grade/10.00 QuizNo
0 1613101016       16SCSE101757 AAYUSH TYAGI 1.csv      5.0        quiz1
1 1613101016 16SCSE101757 AAYUSH TYAGI 1.csv 10.0 quiz2
2 1613101026 16SCSE101415 ABHISHEK 1.csv 7.0 quiz1
3 1613101026 16SCSE101415 ABHISHEK 1.csv 10.0 quiz2
4 1613101051 16SCSE101222 ADITI SINGH 1.csv 5.0 quiz1

Answer (score 0):

You can manually do the following to update the values of the dict with the counter variables.
For example,

```
quiz_result['noofpresent'] = noofpresent #You can do the following for all other keys.
```

**Edit:**

Can you try the following code and tell me what happens. Please preserve the indentaion. As well as that also make sure that the len(quiz_df) > 0.

```
def quizresult(quiz_df):
    maxmarks=10.0
    noofpresent,lessthanfifty,betweenfiftyandsixty,betweensixtyandseventy,betweenseventyandeighty,greaterthaneighty=0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
    quiz_result={'noofpresent':0,'lessthan50':0,'between50and60':0,'between60and70':0,'between70and80':0,'greaterthan80':0}
    for i in range(len(quiz_df)):

        noofpresent=len(quiz_df.index)
        if(float(quiz_df.loc[i,'Grade/10.00'])/maxmarks)<0.5:
            lessthanfifty += 1
        if((float(quiz_df.loc[i,'Grade/10.00'])/maxmarks)>=0.5 and (float(quiz_df.loc[i,'Grade/10.00'])/maxmarks)<0.6):
            betweenfiftyandsixty += 1
        if((float(quiz_df.loc[i,'Grade/10.00'])/maxmarks)>=0.6 and (float(quiz_df.loc[i,'Grade/10.00'])/maxmarks)<0.7):
            betweensixtyandseventy += 1
        if((float(quiz_df.loc[i,'Grade/10.00'])/maxmarks)>=0.7 and (float(quiz_df.loc[i,'Grade/10.00'])/maxmarks)<0.8):
            betweenseventyandeighty += 1
        if(float(quiz_df.loc[i,'Grade/10.00'])/maxmarks)>=0.8:
            greaterthaneighty += 1
    quiz_result.update(noofpresent =noofpresent ,lessthan50=lessthanfifty ,between50and60=betweenfiftyandsixty,between60and70=betweensixtyandseventy, between70and80=betweenseventyandeighty,greaterthan80= greaterthaneighty)

return quiz_result
```

**I am certain that your error is to do with a loop not running or the condtiional statements inside the loop fails and hence doesnt increment the values**

Comment: This isn't entirely correct - you can call the update method with another dictionary... I think the error is actually to do with something else in the OP's code...

Comment: Yes the update method is correct. The problem is to do with  a loop not running or the condtiional statements inside the loop fails and hence doesnt increment the values. I have updated the answer to reflect my words on the update method.

Comment: Checking on that.

Comment: The piece of code below is returning blank dataframe. What is the issue here?
`code`
def filterdataframe(batchno,final_table):
    batchwise_df=final_table[final_table['BatchNo']=='1.csv']
    return batchwise_df
while(len(batchno_fromtestfile)>ibatch):
    batchno=batchno_fromtestfile[ibatch]
    batchwise_df=filterdataframe(batchno,final_table)
    quiz1_df=batchwise_df[batchwise_df['QuizNo']=='quiz1']
    quiz1_result=quizresult(quiz1_df)    
    quiz2_df=batchwise_df[batchwise_df['QuizNo']=='quiz2']
    quiz2_result=quizresult(quiz2_df)
    ibatch+=1

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your indentation is correct? I ran the following piece of code and got the expected dictionary (0.0 as dict values):

```
In [1]: def quizresult(quiz_df):
   ...:     maxmarks=10.0
   ...:     noofpresent,lessthanfifty,betweenfiftyandsixty,betweensixtyandseventy,betweenseventyandeighty,greaterthaneighty=0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
   ...:     quiz_result={'noofpresent':None,'lessthan50':None,'between50and60':None,'between60and70':None,'between70and80':None,'greaterthan80':None}
   ...:     for i in range(len(quiz_df)):
   ...:
   ...:         noofpresent=len(quiz_df.index)
   ...:         if(float(quiz_df.loc[i,'Grade/10.00'])/maxmarks)<0.5:
   ...:             lessthanfifty += 1
   ...:         if((float(quiz_df.loc[i,'Grade/10.00'])/maxmarks)>=0.5 and (float(quiz_df.loc[i,'Grade/10.00'])/maxmarks)<0.6):
   ...:             betweenfiftyandsixty += 1
   ...:         if((float(quiz_df.loc[i,'Grade/10.00'])/maxmarks)>=0.6 and (float(quiz_df.loc[i,'Grade/10.00'])/maxmarks)<0.7):
   ...:             betweensixtyandseventy += 1
   ...:         if((float(quiz_df.loc[i,'Grade/10.00'])/maxmarks)>=0.7 and (float(quiz_df.loc[i,'Grade/10.00'])/maxmarks)<0.8):
   ...:             betweenseventyandeighty += 1
   ...:         if(float(quiz_df.loc[i,'Grade/10.00'])/maxmarks)>=0.8:
   ...:             greaterthaneighty += 1
   ...:     quiz_result.update({'noofpresent':noofpresent,'lessthan50':lessthanfifty,'between50and60':betweenfiftyandsixty,'between60and70':betweensixtyandseventy,'between70and80':betweenseventyandeighty,'greaterthan80':greaterthaneighty})
   ...:
   ...:     return quiz_result
   ...:

In [2]: quizresult([])
Out[2]:
{'noofpresent': 0.0,
 'lessthan50': 0.0,
 'between50and60': 0.0,
 'between60and70': 0.0,
 'between70and80': 0.0,
 'greaterthan80': 0.0}
```

Comment: Indentations is not  problem.

Comment: I get following output: 

{'noofpresent': None, 'lessthan50': None, 'between50and60': None, 'between60and70': None, 'between70and80': None, 'greaterthan80': None} {'noofpresent': None, 'lessthan50': None, 'between50and60': None, 'between60and70': None, 'between70and80': None, 'greaterthan80': None}